# How to run a cucumber scenario multiple times using the data coming from database in using java

Tags: cucumber-jvm

Below is My Scenario:
Scenario: Delete Customer
    Given We declare a new Request
    And We have below Path parameters
      | userid  |  |
      | magcode |  |
    And We have below Header parameters
      | sharedsecret |  |
    And We log the Request
    When We send Delete request to service "DeleteCustomerWebservice"
    Then The response status code should be 200

Here I am deleting customer only once, but same thing i have to do multiple times But the data should be coming from database.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can make your database as datatable for your story. Cucumber isnt designed for this style i believe. Instead handle this in a do/while or for loop inside your test to iterate over all records of resultset.